# clojure.lang.Lazysez cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: loops, clojure, sequence

Hey im making an A* search on a eight puzzle and I have 2 main questions.

*FIXED*: First I get clojure.lang.Lazysez cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn when I run this on the line in the second part of the polymorph in the for loop but im not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
(defn a-star

  ([board history]

     (if  (at-end? board) (println board)
    (

          (let [options (filter #(possible-move? % board) *moves*)
                move (into (pm/priority-map) (for [move options] [move (global-man-dis       (move-tile board move))]))]

              (for [pair move :let [next-move (key pair)]] 

                 (do 
                  (println (move-tile board next-move))
                  (a-star (move-tile board next-move) next-move (conj history board))
                 )
              )
          )
    )))



  ([board prev-move history]

     (if (or (at-end? board) (history-check history board)) (println board)
    (

      (let [options (get-queue board (dont-go-back prev-move))
            move (into (pm/priority-map) (for [move options] [move (global-man-dis     (move-tile board move))]))]

        (for [pair move :let [next-move (key pair)]] 

           (do 
            (println (move-tile board next-move))
            (a-star (move-tile board next-move) next-move (conj history board))
           )
         )
       )
     ))))



(defn -main [& args]
  (println "insert a list all numbers no spaces or letters")
  (def board (mapv (fn [^Character c] (Character/digit c 10)) (read-line)))
  ;(def testt [0 8 4 7 2 1 3 5 6])
  ;(def testt [1 2 3 5 4 6 8 0 7])
  (a-star board [])
  )
```

Tried since post: removing "else" parens around let statement but now returns nothing
*FIXED* removed the else parenthesis and changed for to doseq as for is lazy and wont output anything in this case. ill ask the other question seperatly again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your base cases in a-star return lazy sequences. You are calling the output of a-star as a function, because of the extra pair of parens around the let statements.

Comment: im a little confused which extra parens? I tried removing the "else" parens around the whole let but it just returns nothing now

Comment: see the difference between the following in a repl: `(let [a (constantly true)] a)` `((let [a (constantly true)] a))` - one returns a function, the other returns true.

Comment: By returning nothing do you mean returning nil? If so that is likely because print statements return nil, and you end the branch with a print statement.

Comment: it works now, the problem was that for loops are lazy. before it was printing nothing. I changed it to doseq and now its good. i decided to make this clean and ask my other question to be in a different post